# databases for plant growth temperature and altitude

Tags: botany, database

Does anyone know databases which have info for plant growth temperature.It could be specific numbers or categorization as 'cold, warm,tropical and etc' ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You might find these maps useful. I am not sure where you live, but most plants will list what region they will grow in on their seed packet or online.

You might also find luck by searching ESRI or ArcGIS maps to find more information.

http://www.ahs.org/gardening-resources/gardening-maps